# Logic Pro X: keyboard shortcut to move the playhead to the begining of selected region

Tags: logic-pro

Is there a keyboard shortcut to move the play-head to the beginning of the selected region?

When I try to edit the shortcuts, I don't find anything similar.

Comment: Ctrl-End goes to END of selected region

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For US Keyboard layout, it's Control-Home.
[image: Go To Selection Start - LPX]

If you want to play selected region(s), it's Shift-SpaceBar
[image: Play from Selection - LPX]

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is spot on - just wanted to add one important thing...

If you're using a laptop - **ctrl-home** is produced by pressing **ctrl-fn** and the **left** arrow key.

Comment: yes, that was part of the problem :)

Answer (score -2):

Go to navigate, then scroll down to play button options then click on play from selected region, and this feature will always be enabled